# How to find out the memory usage of particular function in a process (C Program) in linux?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

```
I would like to find out the memory consumed by particular function in linux.
```

How do i find out the exact memory usage of  function_net() in a process (C program)?

Is there any system call in linux to find out the same?

```
For example:

/* How to find out the memory usage of this function */

**void function_net()
{
   int *a = (int *)malloc(200);
}**

 #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   function_net();
}
```

Comment: Once the code is compiled, there isn't really any "functions" in the generated code, not in the same sense as the original C concept of functions. All you have are jumps between different parts of the code, and the Linux kernel have no idea of what "function" some allocation comes from. There are tools that can help you, like e.g. [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) which traces system calls (like `malloc`), profilers and debuggers, which all of them basically requires you to run a debug-build to get any sensible information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to check using pmap?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the compiler to generate the assembly source output as a separate file during compile phase or the linker to output a map file during the link phase of the build. It may however be optimised out